Можно ли на ajax получить из заголовка токен и потом сделать редирект с этим же токеном?
У меня есть обработчик на ajax, который делает POST-запрос на бек и бек дает ответ. Причем токен лежит не в теле ответа а в загловке:
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url_send,
        data: JSON.stringify({
                uid: uid,
                password: password
              }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(response) {
                if (response.succes) {
                    window.location.href = '/secret';
                }
                else {
                    alert(response.error);
                }
              },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.error('Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса:', textStatus, errorThrown);
              }
            });

Собственно сам вопрос: можно ли мне вытащить этот токен из заголовка и сделать редирект на страницу с указанным токеном также в заголовке (не хочу светить токен в URL и теле)

В каком заголовке? Некоторые заголовки можно прочитать, если разрешит сервер, некоторые нельзя читать никогда, например Set-Cookie.

Обычный заголовок я в беке на API в заголовок кинул token, который и хочу прочитать без перезагрузки страницы - чисто методом POST

Непонятно только как вы собираетесь отправлять редирект с токеном. Браузер так не умеет. Пр редиректе браузер отправит те заголовки которые посчитает нужным. Например куки отправит, а ваши кастомные заголовки нет. В общем, кажется вам надо не изобретать велосипед, а использовать куки.

Куки пользователь может отключить

а касаемо установки полученного токена в заголовке- да. по ходу беда...

success: function(data, textStatus, request){
    let token = request.getResponseHeader('my_token_key_name');
},


надо ещё дописать про https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

хм.. токен я получил, а вот его теперь получается я не смогу передать также в заголовке через window.location.href?

@Алексей для передачи заголовков со стороны js используется ajax/fetch/сохранённые cookie
